# Tools for conceptual website design

Tags: prototyping

What tools (apart from Visio) will generate visually pleasing website site maps or diagrams of a conceptual website?

We want to present nice diagrams to our client, but we're unsure about where to get started—we're all coders, not designers.

Visio shapes or stencils are quite old. What tools are others in the industry using?

Comment: What problems do you have with Visio that you want to resolve?

Comment: initially i think its just out dated stencils, I want something thats like the Powerpoint-esque objects (nice gradient'd OmniGraph style items).

Comment: You might get better answers for this question at http://doctype.com/.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst not in the same category as Visio I am a huge fan of the wire framing tools provided by [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/). While on the topic of wire framing (which is useful in addition to site map tools like Visio) [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/01/35-excellent-wireframing-resources/) recently had an excellent article on wire framing resource.

Answer (score 2):

**[Microsoft SketchFlow](https://web.archive.org/web/20150430043430/http://www.microsoft.com:80/Expression/products/SketchFlow_Overview.aspx)**

http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Sketchflow_Overview.aspx

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/media/sfSketch.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/media/sfMap.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/media/sfFeedback.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Do you know if SketchFlow included in Expression Blend or is it stand alone component?

Comment: It is included in Expression Blend.

Answer (score 0):

I use illustrator to draw basic boxes for very raw webpage layout images.
Previously I used Photoshop to build visually complex mockups of websites. Now I skip the photshop stage and go straight to code.

I use a css framework called blueprint (http://www.blueprintcss.org/) to quickly build interfaces. It includes a grid system, css reset, typography and forms, etc.

Sitemaps can be drawn using mind mapping software. I use omni graffle (I work on a mac) It works well.